# Possible scam confirmation email

Tags: scams

I have received a confirmation email from an unknown sender in my email account on my mac which I have been previously logged into it so all the messages being sent have been kept popping up everyday. At the beginning when it firstly popped up on my mac screen I thought it was just a newsletter of some kind of website which I might have been possibly subscribed to.

However, when I looked at it again once opened, it says that I have ordered a product called "Cool Stuff" which I have never ordered and is ready for collection at Australia Post. Surprisingly, this email also included my actual shipping address correctly, which I remember I've never given any of my personal detail to this sender, and showed my payment method was debit/mastercard and a tracking number.

So I deleted the email soon after and thought it might be a scam. Then when I logged into my email account using the offical website rather than directly on my mac and checked the deleted email, I saw it was like a newsletter just about promotion but was still from the same sender. It literally looked like a different content than the previous one. I have no idea how could I receive such a shipping order **when I have never even went on the website recently so how could I possibly ordered one?**

Comment: Did you start browsing the internet recently ? If not, you should have seen these type of emails daily. They are SPAM and are trying to hook unsuspecting users like you who assume they are genuine. If you haven't ordered online anything and your bank cards show nothing why do you care about these emails ? DELETE THEM and move ahead. Your real address appears means your personal details might have been available online to some hackers from some website you might have used before, which is a common occurrence if you aren't careful.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it's somewhat trivial for a hacker to obtain a name and it's "real" address, so don't take it for granted that the email is legitimate just because it has your address in it.

Answer (score 3):

> I have no idea how could I receive such a shipping order when I have
>   never even went on the website recently so how could I possibly
>   ordered one?

Sometimes a semi-legitimate site will tack on a service or product that you didn't notice to the transaction you thought you were making.

Here are a few examples that I know people have had to deal with:

- register for a 5K race, and not notice that in the fine print you agreed to a service that would charge you $9.99 a month for the opportunity to get discounts on products. The first month is free so you aren't aware of it until you check your credit card bill a few months after you registered for the race.
- A anti-virus company sends you to their download page, and then gives you a page with a big download button, but obscures the fact that the button is to agree to accept another piece of software that will cost you more money.

It is easy to imagine that you ordered something on a site, but they tricked into a monthly subscription for a related product.

You need to track it down, and if you didn't know you were ordering it then complain, return the item and demand a refund.

Answer (score 0):

There's the possibility that this is phishing, but it seems relatively unlikely. Most phishing groups would probably give you a link to click on that asked you to enter in your credentials (username/password/credit or debit card info). It sounds like this one just wanted to send you to the post office.

Double-check your credit/debit card for a purchase from that company, and if you have one, dispute the charges. Otherwise-- are you certain that the credit/debit card number on the email was yours? The holidays are rapidly approaching. Is there a possibility that a friend or family member got you a gift and had it shipped to Australian post for you?